# "Undefined reference" error with shared library and ldflags

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, qemu

When trying to compile my code inside QEMU using make, I get an `undefined reference` error during the linking phase. Afaik the configure parameters are correct, so the shared library should be used correctly for the linking, but maybe I have overlooked something.

Any help would be appreciated!

Below is a lot of additional information I already collected:

---

Solution: See [Zach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19367803/1537754)

I managed it now by adding `LIBS+=-lcity` to the `Makefile.target` file.

Thanks to all!

---

Update:

**`make V=1` output:**

```
cc -Werror -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef
-Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -I/home/user/cityhash
-Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs
-Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers
-Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits
-fstack-protector-all -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1     -I/usr/include/libpng12
-I/usr/include/pixman-1     -I../linux-headers -I..
-I/home/user/qemu/target-i386 -DNEED_CPU_H -I/home/user/qemu/include -pthread
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -O2
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
-L/home/user/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/lib -lcity -o qemu-system-x86_64 [… all
*.o files … ] ../libqemuutil.a ../libqemustub.a   -lrt -pthread -lgthread-2.0
-lrt -lglib-2.0    -lutil -lrbd -lrados -lbluetooth   -lcurl   -lncurses -ltinfo
-lbrlapi  -luuid -lpng12   -ljpeg -lsasl2 -lgnutls   -lSDL   -lX11  -lz -laio
-lpixman-1   -lm
```

This is followed by the normal error output I've written below (except for the `LINK`, which is missing in this case).

---

**Error:**

```
~/qemu$ make
...
  LINK  x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64
my_code.o: In function `function`:
/home/user/qemu/my_code.c:982: undefined reference to `CityHash64'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [qemu-system-x86_64] Error 1
make: *** [subdir-x86_64-softmmu] Error 2
```

**Configure paramters:**

```
./configure [...] \
    --extra-cflags='-I/home/user/cityhash' \
    --extra-ldflags='-L/home/user/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/lib -lcity'
```

**Folder structure:**

```
~
├─ cityhash/
│  ├─ city.h
│  └─ ...
├─ lib/
│  ├─ libcity.so
│  └─ ...
└─ qemu/
```

**Header include and function usage (my_code.c):**

```
[...]
 11  #include "city.h"

982  hash = CityHash64(buf, len);
[...]
```

**Nm output for the shared library:**

```
~/lib$ nm libcity.so
[...]
0000000000000fdc T CityHash64
[...]
```

**Strace output during make:**

```
~/qemu$ strace -f -o ../strace.out -- make
[...]
16111 stat("/home/user/lib/libcity.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18468, ...}) = 0
16111 open("/home/user/lib/libcity.so", O_RDONLY) = 7
16111 fcntl(7, F_GETFD)                 = 0
16111 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
16111 fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18468, ...}) = 0
16111 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2aaaaaad9000
16111 lseek(7, 0, SEEK_SET)             = 0
16111 read(7, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\7\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 brk(0x2129000)                    = 0x2129000
16111 lseek(7, 12288, SEEK_SET)         = 12288
16111 read(7, "9\23\2%\25\0\2\4\1\364\0\2\4\1\2E\23\0\2\4\1\2>\23\0\2\4\1\203\0\2\4"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 16384, SEEK_SET)         = 16384
16111 lseek(7, 16384, SEEK_SET)         = 16384
16111 lseek(7, 0, SEEK_SET)             = 0
16111 read(7, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\7\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 12288, SEEK_SET)         = 12288
16111 read(7, "9\23\2%\25\0\2\4\1\364\0\2\4\1\2E\23\0\2\4\1\2>\23\0\2\4\1\203\0\2\4"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 0, SEEK_SET)             = 0
16111 read(7, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\7\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 8192, SEEK_SET)          = 8192
16111 read(7, "\6\2\233\f\7\10\0\0$\0\0\0\314\1\0\0\314\354\377\377\210\0\0\0\0A\16\20\206\2C\r"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 12288, SEEK_SET)         = 12288
16111 lseek(7, 12288, SEEK_SET)         = 12288
16111 lseek(7, 12288, SEEK_SET)         = 12288
16111 lseek(7, 12288, SEEK_SET)         = 12288
16111 read(7, "9\23\2%\25\0\2\4\1\364\0\2\4\1\2E\23\0\2\4\1\2>\23\0\2\4\1\203\0\2\4"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 8192, SEEK_SET)          = 8192
16111 read(7, "\6\2\233\f\7\10\0\0$\0\0\0\314\1\0\0\314\354\377\377\210\0\0\0\0A\16\20\206\2C\r"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 0, SEEK_SET)             = 0
16111 read(7, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\7\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
16111 lseek(7, 4096, SEEK_SET)          = 4096
[...]
16111 close(7)                          = 0
[...]
```

Comment: Is that error from a link or a simple .c compile? Given the message, I think a compile. If so, have you included the right .h file in .c file  that is being compiled? The ld error messages do not usually give the line of the reference.

Comment: @CharlieBurns The error occurs during the linking, I forgot and now added this information in the `make` output in my question. The header file is correct, as is the path in the `cflags`.

Comment: This is probably not the problem but: check the actual link command to make sure the lib comes after the .o file.

Comment: @CharlieBurns I couldn't find the actual link command, since the [Makefile](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob_plain;f=Makefile;hb=HEAD) of QEMU is a bit complicated, but it works on another machine with the same Makefile, so I'm pretty sure the Makefile places the flags in the correct order.

Comment: The link command is probably in one the Makefiles in the subtree that the top level Makefile calls. On the machine where it works, was .configure called in exactly the same way? The actual link command may show up in the log file just before or after that "LINK" comment. Or they may have silenced it which is a pain in the ass. In any event, it's a mystery, do let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: Show the `gcc` invocation on the linkage stage. Does it even find `libcity.so`?

Comment: @Haroogan, the strace would seem to say it does. But it's unknown if that strace comes from the link or some other make induced program. I agree that the way to solve this is find the actual link command line.If the OP's .ofile came after the lib in the command line, it could do what the OP is seeing.

Comment: Which should be pretty easy with something like `grep -r "\-lcity" .`, isn't it?

Comment: Not if the Makefile made it silent by prepending the command with @. But I agree, the logfile is the place to look. OP doesn't seem interested anymore.

Comment: Grepping the directory actually finds a log file, which unfortunately only logs gcc and ld commands used (a lot of them) to compile to a temporary target during the configuration. I'll add them to the question.

Comment: Temporary replace your `gcc` and `ld` programs with scripts that call the actual programs and log everything they can.

Comment: It looks like you've discovered why default silent rules are a Bad Thing.  Repeat the link with `make V=1` and the uninformative `LINK ...` line in the make output should be replaced with the actual linker invocation, which is the thing we need to know in order to debug.

Comment: FYI, the error you found in `config.log` is completely unrelated, and the `strace` output is actually *too finegrained* to be useful - we would need to correlate the bit you quoted with other bits that are probably thousands of lines above and below.

Comment: @Zack With `make V=1`, no `LINK ...` line appears at all. It does only print a cc line followed by the output in the OP. However, `make -n` prints the `LINK ...` line. I'll include both in the OP.

Comment: Yes, the `cc` line is what I was looking for.

Comment: Looks like the `-lcity` really comes after the *.o files. I don't think the QEMU Makefile can't handle ldflags correctly, is that really what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this appears to be a link ordering issue.  The key bits of the link command line are:

```
-g -L/home/user/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/lib -lcity -o qemu-system-x86_64
```

and then

```
[... all *.o files ...] ../libqemuutil.a ../libqemustub.a 
-lrt -pthread -lgthread2.0 [... more libraries ...]
```

The problem is that `-lcity` needs to come *after* all of the `.o` files on the command line, because order matters: libraries are only searrched for unresolved symbols from object files that *precede* them on the command line.

This is probably an Automake-generated Makefile, which means that you need to get `-lcity` into `LDADD` for the offending link operation, rather than `LDFLAGS`.  It *may* be possible to accomplish this with an `--extra-libs=-lcity` configure option (remove `-lcity` from `--extra-ldflags`, but keep everything else you have in there).  If not, try `make LDADD=-lcity`.  If *that* doesn't work (it has fairly high odds of clobbering other stuff that needs to be in `LDADD`) you are going to have to dig into the *generated* Makefile (it won't be apparent from Makefile.am) and see if there's another variable you can set on the command line.

Comment: FWIW, I found `LDLIBS` to be what worked for me in a related situation (no `configure`, just default `make` rules, which I examined with `make -p -f/dev/null`, per the man page).  `LDLIBS` was what the implicit rules were using, so that's what got my linking to work (I'd been trying `LDFLAGS`, and based on this tried `LDADD`, but `LDLIBS` was the winner.)